# JavaScript closure, about object and this

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function abc(v){
    console.log(v);
}

var abcd= abc;

var module = {
    name: "hello",
    innerFunc: function(){
        console.log("name "+name);

    },
    outterFunc: abc("run from module")
}
```

Is there a way to in `innerFunc` to refer the value of `name`?

My thought is there should be a way, since they are all in the `module` object. I could be totally wrong.

Please tell me why and why not?

PS:

Actually, I figured out by adding the following code to it

```
var module = {
    name: "hello",
    innerFunc: function(){
        var self = this;
        console.log("name "+self.name);
    },
    outterFunc: abc("run from module")
}
```

So, the follow up question is that, why `innerFunc` is not running like `outterFunc`, `outterFunc` is invoked immediate after the running the code, why does `innerFunc` has to be explicitly called as `module.innerFunc()`.

Thanks

Comment: Because you are calling `abc("run from module")` and assigning its return value to `outterFunc` (the spelling out "outer" is wrong), whereas for `innerFunc` you are just assigning a function expression to the property without calling it. Hence you can call it afterwards using `module.innerFunc`. Are you confused about first-class functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to alias `this` to `self` to use instance properties.  You can just write `innerFunc` like so:

```
innerFunc: function(){
    console.log("name "+this.name);
},
```

You've probably seeing `var self = this` in other code examples, and it is a common way to get around the fact that `this` changes as you descend into function scopes.  It's not a technique I care for...it's usually more clear to use a meaningful variable name.  In your case, however, it's not necessary to alias `this` to `self` at all.

To answer your second question, it's important to understand the difference between function *definition* and function *invocation*.

When you *define* a function, it is not being executed -- no matter where it's defined.  Consider the following example:

```
function f() {
    console.log('f');
}
var o = {
    m: function() {
        console.log('m');
    }
}
```

In that example, there are two function definitions, but no function invocations.  In other words, if you run this script, the function `f` will exist, and the method `o.m` will exist, but neither will have been executed, so there will be nothing printed on the command line.  In general, if you see the keyword `function`, you're dealing with a function definition, *not* an invocation.  The following code now invokes both of these functions in turn:

```
f();
o.m();
```

In this case, the two calls to `console.log` will happen.

In your example, you're *defining* the property `outerFunc` by *invoking* the function `abc` (which I suspect is not what you want to do).  How do I know you're invoking it?  Because there are parentheses and no `function` keyword:

```
var module = {
    //...
    outterFunc: abc("run from module")
}
```

What's happening here is `abc` is getting *invoked* and its *return value* is getting assigned to `outerFunc`.  Since `abc` returns nothing, `outerFunc` will get the value `undefined`.  Which is why I'm guessing that is not what you want.  If you want `m.outerFunc` to be an *alias* of `abc`, you would do that this way:

```
var module = {
    //...
    outerFunc: abc
}
```

Note there are no parentheses...so `abc` is *not* invoked.  Now `module.outerFunc` is an alias for `abc`.  Be careful, though!  This is a dangerous way to alias functions in JavaScript...in this instance, it's probably okay because you're aliasing a function (not a method), so there's little danger of `this` not being what you expect, but you'll run into that if you try to alias methods to one another.  So in general, this technique should be used with caution.

If you want `outerFunc` to *call* `abc`, you will have to do this:

```
var module = {
    //...
    outerFunc: function() {
        abc();
    }
}
```

In this case, `abc` is *not* being invoked...it is inside a function definition, so it will only be invoked when `m.outerFunc` is invoked.

I know this can all seem very confusing at first, but these are really important distinctions to understand, so please let me know if this answer isn't clear.